# A question on application of derivatives

Tags: integration, derivatives, leibniz-integral-rule

> If the area of the circle increases at a uniform rate, show that the rate of increase of the circumference varies inversely as the radius.

My approach-

If area is increasing at a uniform rate then the area function should be $A(r)=pr+q$ where $p$ and $q$ are certain constants and $r$ is the radius of the circle.

We can say that-
$$A(r)=\int_0^r C(r)dr$$where $C(r)$ is the circumference as a function of $r$.

Now differentiating both sides with respect to $r$-
$$A'(r)=\frac{d}{dr}(\int_0^r C(r)dr)$$

Now, using [Newton-Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)-
$$p=C(r)$$

Circumference turns out to be a constant quantity! Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The rate should be the speed... or else this will result in $A(r)=\pi r^2=pr+q$ which gives us a quadratic equation with finitely many roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you assumed that the area is linear with $r$- but the relationship between $A$ and $r$ is fixed: $A= \pi r^2$. What the question means is a constant $A'(t)$ ($A$ is linear with *time*). If you use the above $A(r)$, you'll get the desired result.

Comment: I was thinking that. I think I got confused with what "rate" was.